# Table cells data gets collapsed when generating PDF using flying saucer v 9.1.20

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer, openpdf

We are using latest version of flying saucer v 9.1.20, In that the table columns are collapsed when there are large number of columns (Eg: 80 columns).

We have also added ***word-wrap: break-word*** for cells to break the word when needed and also used ***table-layout: fixed*** for tables.

It works when the column count is low, but when columns gets increased, the property is not being applied and column gets collapsed.

Have attached the screen shots and sample code. Have anyone faced this issue, kindly let us know the solution for this.

**Table in browser view**
[image: table in browser view]

**Table in PDF generated using flying saucer**
[image]

**HTML Code**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    .table-column {
       font-size: 10px;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       word-wrap: break-word;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;word-wrap: break-word;width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
          Column1
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column2
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column3
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column4
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column5
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column6
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column7
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column8
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column9
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column10
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column11
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column12
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column13
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column14
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column15
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column16
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column17
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column18
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column19
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column20
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column21
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column22
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column23
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column24
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column25
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column26
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column27
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column28
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column29
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column30
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column31
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column32
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column33
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column34
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column35
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column36
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column37
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column38
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column39
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column40
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column41
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column42
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column43
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column44
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column45
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column46
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column47
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column48
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column49
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column50
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column51
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column52
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column53
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column54
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column55
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column56
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column57
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column58
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column59
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column60
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column61
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column62
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column63
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column64
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column65
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column66
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column67
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column68
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column69
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column70
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column71
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column72
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column73
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column74
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column75
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column76
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column78
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column79
        </td>
        <td class="table-column" style="width: 15%;word-wrap: break-word;">
           Column80
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't say for sure if this is the cause but you have specified a width of 15% for 80 columns = a total of 1200% but total width % of all cells must be limited to 100%. Maybe flying saucer is getting confused by the impossible total percentage value?